# Why do browsers use my saved password for all forms in the one site?

Tags: html, autocomplete, passwords, credentials, browser

Is there a way to limit the url of saved credentials in browsers?

For example, if I save a username and password for `http://www.website.com/login` can I make it so that the rest of the forms in the site don't use these details? `http://www.website.com/members`, `http://www.website.com/admin` etc...

I'm aware of the autocomplete attribute but I don't want to turn off autocomplete entirely. I would like it if the browser remembered the login details per form or url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, browsers simply remember details for a base domain (or subdomain). You can't set it to remember credentials for only specific pages. (Note that domain.com and www.domain.com are considered different domains).

Comment: oh well, maybe I will have a look for an addon that would do this. Thanks